# How to trigger a bash script from right click in Safari on a particular URL?

Tags: macos, safari, bash, script

is it possible when I'm in Safari and have link (URL) to trigger a bach script with an right mouse option?

The bach script should be run with this format: 
bash scriptname.sh -parameter -parameter URL

Thanks!

Comment: Look up Automator Services. Create one with '**Run Shell Scripts'**. Set the service to only be available in Safari with text. So you can `Right Click > Services > Run My Script`. There are other excellent third party applications for this; my recommendation Keyboard Maestro.

Answer (score 1):

No - Safari is designed to not run code like that.

Could you imagine the damage someone would do with a malicious script to delete all a user's photos if they get them to click a link that could say anything and link to a malicious script underneath?